# RxJS Subscription Service in Webworker

Tags: javascript, jquery, functional-programming, observer-pattern, frp

[Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rrdPgQpXrLXLgnIn6l57?p=preview) of my working demo.

I have the following code which I have created for a subscription service for data through a webworker. I was wondering if I was following functional-reactive programming best practices and patterns on the webworker. I am new to RxJS and none of our team at work has ever used it, but we really see it's potential in this demo. I am not sure how to refactor the code to avoid the use of side-effects and the like. Any tips whatsoever on the code would be good.

script.js:

```
var worker = new Worker('webworker.js');

var subscriberIDs= {};

var idGen = (function idGen () {
  var id = 0;
  return function () {
    return id++;
  };
})();

function renderSuggestion(suggestedUser, selector) {
    var suggestionEl = document.querySelector(selector);
    if (suggestedUser === null) {
        suggestionEl.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    } else {
        suggestionEl.style.visibility = 'visible';
        var usernameEl = suggestionEl.querySelector('.username');
        usernameEl.href = suggestedUser.html_url;
        usernameEl.textContent = suggestedUser.login;
        var imgEl = suggestionEl.querySelector('img');
        imgEl.src = "";
        imgEl.src = suggestedUser.avatar_url;
    }
}

function onError(e) {
    console.log([
      'ERROR: Line ', e.lineno, ' in ', e.filename, ': ', e.message
    ].join(''));
  }

worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  if(subscriberIDs[e.data.cmd]) {
    renderSuggestion(e.data.msg, '.suggestion[data-id="' + e.data.cmd + '"]');
  }
}, false);

worker.addEventListener('error', onError, false);
$(function () {
  $(".subscribe").click(function () {
    var subID = idGen();
    subscriberIDs[subID] = true;
    $("#subscriptions").append(createSubEl(subID));
    worker.postMessage({cmd: "subscribe", msg: {subscription: "github/users", subscriberID: subID} });  
  });
  $(document).on("click", ".unsubscribe", function (e) {
    var subID = $(this).attr("data-id");
    delete subscriberIDs[subID];
    worker.postMessage({cmd: "unsubscribe", msg: {subscription: "github/users", subscriberID: subID} });  
    $(this).closest(".suggestion").remove();
  });
  $("#updateTime").on("change", function () {
    var timeVal = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    worker.postMessage({cmd: "updateSubTime", msg: {subscription: "github/users", time: timeVal } });
  })
});

function createSubEl (subscriberID) {
  return $(`<div class="suggestion" data-id="${subscriberID}" style="visibility:hidden;">
      <input input type="button" value="unsubscribe" class="unsubscribe pull-right btn btn-info" data-id="${subscriberID}">
      <img />
      <a href="#" target="_blank" class="username">this will not be displayed</a>
    </div>`);
}
```

webworker.js:

```
importScripts("rxjs.min.js");
importScripts("underscore.min.js");
importScripts("io.js");

var sources = {};
var subscriptions = {};

// Code goes here
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  var data = e.data;
  switch (data.cmd) {
    case 'subscribe':
      var msg = data.msg;
      insertSubscription(msg.subscription, msg.subscriberID);
      break;
    case 'unsubscribe':
      var msg = data.msg;
      removeSubscription(msg.subscription, msg.subscriberID);
      break;
    case 'updateSubTime':
      var msg = data.msg;
      updateSubTime(msg.subscription, msg.time);
      break;
    default:
      self.postMessage('Unknown command: ' + data.msg);
  };
}, false);

function insertSubscription(subscription, subscriberID) {
  if(!sources[subscription]) {
    sources[subscription] = {};
    sources[subscription].subscriptions = {};
    sources[subscription].subscriptions[subscriberID] = false;
    createSource(subscription);
  }

  createSubscription(subscription, subscriberID, function (data) {
    self.postMessage({cmd: subscriberID, msg: data});
  });
}

function createSource (subscription) {
  var callInterval = 0;
  if(sources[subscription]) {
    Rx.Observable.interval(60 * 1000).startWith(0).map(function () {
      return 'https://api.github.com/rate_limit';
      /*
      example
      {
        "resources": {
          "core": {
            "limit": 5000,
            "remaining": 4999,
            "reset": 1372700873
          },
          "search": {
            "limit": 30,
            "remaining": 18,
            "reset": 1372697452
          }
        },
        "rate": {
          "limit": 5000,
          "remaining": 4999,
          "reset": 1372700873
        }
      }
      */
    }).flatMap(function (requestUrl) {
      return get(requestUrl).then(function(data) {
        var rateLimit = JSON.parse(data).resources;
        // get times in milliseconds
        var timeOfReset = rateLimit.core.reset * 1000;
        var timeNow = (new Date()).getTime();
        var numSubscriptions = Object.keys(sources[subscription].subscriptions).length;
        var callInterval =  (timeOfReset - timeNow) / (rateLimit.core.remaining + numSubscriptions);
        console.log(rateLimit);
        console.log(callInterval);
        return callInterval;
      });
    }).subscribe(function (interval) {
      callInterval = interval
    });
    if(!sources[subscription].observable || !sources[subscription].subject) {
      var randomOffset = Math.floor(Math.random()*500);
      var currentPosition = 0;
      var cacheData = [];
      sources[subscription].subject = new Rx.Subject();

      sources[subscription].observable = sources[subscription].subject
        .startWith(5000)
        .flatMapLatest(function(intvl){
          return Rx.Observable.interval(Math.max(1000, intvl, callInterval)).startWith("something");
        })
        //.bufferWithTime(1000)
        .take(10)
        .map(function() {
            return 'https://api.github.com/users?since=' + randomOffset++;
        })
        .flatMap(function (requestUrl) {
          if(cacheData[currentPosition]) {
              return Promise.resolve(cacheData[currentPosition++]);
          } else {
            currentPosition = 0;
            var promise = get(requestUrl).then(function(data) {
              cacheData = JSON.parse(data);
              var dataToSend = cacheData[currentPosition];
              currentPosition++;
              return dataToSend;
            });
            return promise;
          }
        });

      sources[subscription].subject.onNext(5000);
    }
  }
}

function updateSubTime (subscription, time) {
  if(sources[subscription] && sources[subscription].subject) {
    sources[subscription].subject.onNext(time);
  }
}

function createSubscription(subscription, subscriberID, subCallback){
  console.log("heretoo");
  if(sources[subscription] && !sources[subscription].subscriptions[subscriberID] && typeof subCallback == "function") {
    console.log("herethree");
    sources[subscription].subscriptions[subscriberID] = sources[subscription].observable.subscribe(subCallback);
  } 
}

function removeSubscription (subscription, subscriberID) {
  if(sources[subscription] && sources[subscription].subscriptions[subscriberID]) {
    sources[subscription].subscriptions[subscriberID].dispose();
    delete sources[subscription].subscriptions[subscriberID];
  }
}
```

Comment: Please state only code purpose in the title.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Code Review. If there are tags you want, you can request them, and we can decide if they are fit to be a tag!

Comment: @TheCoffeeCup how would I go about making a tag request would I do that on meta code review with the `[tag-creation]` tag?

Comment: @John I assume so.

Comment: Top level var `subscriptions` is not used.

Comment: How are the string replacements in `createSubEl()` achieved?

Comment: What is the mystery variable `self`?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 string replacement is done through [es6 template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings). Self is like the global scope of a [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers). Thanks about the subscription not being used I refactored and forgot to remove it.

Comment: @John, ah OK, I forgot about ES6 template_strings. One of those things I read about but never used. Thanks for the  link. But are there not environments that offer web workers and *not* ES6. If so (and you want to target them), then it's very simple to use jQuery to set those `data-id` values, eg. `return $('<div....../div>').find("input").addBack().data('id', subscriberID);`.

Comment: @Roamer-1888. That's true, but I'm using [babel](https://babeljs.io/), a es6 to es5 transpiler, in production so it's not that big of an issue.

Comment: BTW: looks cool.

Comment: I think the caching needs looking at. Presumably the cache should grow to length==10 (compatible with `.take(10)`), then cycle through. At the very least I think `cacheData = JSON.parse(data)` should read `cacheData[currentPosition] = JSON.parse(data);`, and you need `currentPosition = currentPosition % 10` in there somewhere, and `currentPosition = 0` should disappear.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 The subscribing observables may only take 10 but the cache is used across all subscriptions of that observable. If you check the network out you can tell this is true because it only makes 1 request every 20 or so users it shows. (exhausting all users in each request.) That was the idea behind the cache to just cache the last request of that `source` so that all the subscriptions of that source could use it till it needed more. The take(10) was mainly just a temporary thing to make sure that I didn't run out of requests or something if I left it running, it will be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, trying to answer the specific review objectives ...

> I was wondering if I was following functional-reactive programming best practices and patterns on the webworker.

I'm not really an FRP expert so can't really comment on that aspect *per se*, however, I can show you how to better organise your code.

> I am not sure how to refactor the code to avoid the use of side-effects and the like.

The worst feature of "webworker.js" as it stands, is the need to pass `subscription` to almost every function, so `sources[subscription]` (and its properties) can be operated on. This can be avoided by factoring the code into Constructors (classes if you like), each with a bunch of methods.

I found that the code fell very naturally into three Constructors :

- `Sources()` - what was `var sources = {}`
- `Subscription()` - what was all over the place
- `Observable()` - what was `createSource()` but no longer creates its own `subject`

The three work hierarchically such that :

- top level code (the switch-case structure) is aware of `Sources()`
- `Sources()` is aware of `Subscription()`
- `Subscription()` is aware of `Observable()`

*Note: `Observable()` doesn't have any methods and isn't really necessary. It avoids a lot of bulk in `Subscription()`.*

**webworker.js :**

The result is highly readable, object-oriented code (untested) :

```
importScripts("rxjs.min.js");
importScripts("underscore.min.js");
importScripts("io.js");
var sources = new Sources();
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    switch(data.cmd) {
        case 'subscribe':
            sources.subscribe(e.data.msg.subscription, e.data.msg.subscriberID);
        break;
        case 'unsubscribe':
            sources.unsubscribe(e.data.msg.subscription, e.data.msg.subscriberID);
        break;
        case 'updateSubTime':
            sources.updateSubTime(e.data.msg.subscription, e.data.msg.time);
        break;
        default:
            self.postMessage('Unknown command: ' + e.data.msg);
    };
}, false);

// **********************************
// *** start: Sources constructor ***
// **********************************
function Sources() {
    this.sources = {};
}
Sources.prototype.subscribe = function(subscriptionID, subscriberID) {
    if(!this.sources[subscriptionID]) {
        this.sources[subscriptionID] = (new Subscription()).updateSubTime(5000);
    }
    this.sources[subscriptionID].subscribe(subscriberID, function(data) {
        self.postMessage({cmd: subscriberID, msg: data});
    });
    return this; //for method chaining
};
Sources.prototype.unsubscribe = function(subscriptionID, subscriberID) {
    this.sources[subscriptionID].unsubscribe(subscriberID);
    return this; //for method chaining
}
Sources.prototype.updateSubTime = function(subscriptionID, time) {
    this.sources[subscriptionID].updateSubTime(time);
    return this; //for method chaining
}
// ********************************
// *** fin: Sources constructor ***
// ********************************

// ***************************************
// *** start: Subscription constructor ***
// ***************************************
function Subscription() {
    this.subject = new Rx.Subject();
    this.subscriptions = {};
    this.observable = new Observable(this.subject, this.subscriptions);
}
Subscription.prototype.subscribe = function(subscriberID, callback) {
    this.subscriptions[subscriberID] = this.observable.subscribe(callback);
    return this; //for method chaining
};
Subscription.prototype.unsubscribe = function(subscriberID) {
    if(this.subscriptions[subscriberID]) {
        this.subscriptions[subscriberID].dispose();
        delete this.subscriptions[subscriberID];
        return this; //for method chaining
    }
};
Subscription.prototype.updateSubTime = function(time) {
    this.subject.onNext(time);
    return this; //for method chaining
};
// *************************************
// *** fin: Subscription constructor ***
// *************************************

// *************************************
// *** start: Observable constructor ***
// *************************************
function Observable(subject, subscriptions) {
    var callInterval = 0;
    Rx.Observable.interval(60 * 1000).startWith(0).map(function () {
        return 'https://api.github.com/rate_limit';
    }).flatMap(function(requestUrl) {
        return get(requestUrl).then(function(data) {
            var rateLimit = JSON.parse(data).resources;
            return (rateLimit.core.reset * 1000 - Date.now()) / (rateLimit.core.remaining + Object.keys(subscriptions).length);
        });
    }).subscribe(function(interval) {
        callInterval = interval;
    });
    var randomOffset = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
    var currentPosition = 0;
    var cacheData = [];
    return subject
    .startWith(5000)
    .flatMapLatest(function(intvl) {
        return Rx.Observable.interval(Math.max(1000, intvl, callInterval)).startWith('something');
    })
    //.bufferWithTime(1000)
    .take(10)
    .map(function() {
        return 'https://api.github.com/users?since=' + randomOffset++;
    })
    .flatMap(function(requestUrl) {
        if(!cacheData[currentPosition]) {
            cacheData[currentPosition] = get(requestUrl).then(function(data) {
                return JSON.parse(data);
            });
        }
        var promise = cacheData[currentPosition];
        currentPosition = (currentPosition + 1) % 10;
        return promise;
    });
}
// ***********************************
// *** fin: Observable constructor ***
// ***********************************
```

I'm not sure about my caching strategy. From what you say in comments above, you may need to revert to what you had originally.

**script.js :**

"script.js" doesn't really need to be touched. The `{cmd: ..., msg: ... }` messaging protocol is unchanged.

I've just made a few tweeks.

```
// Everything can be wrapped in $(function () {...});, not just the event listeners
$(function () { 
    var worker = new Worker('webworker.js');
    var subscriberIDs = {};
    var idGen = (function idGen() {
        var id = 0;
        return function() {
            return id++;
        };
    })();
    function renderSuggestion(suggestedUser, selector) {
        if(suggestedUser) {
            $(selector).show().find('img').attr('src', suggestedUser.avatar_url).end().find('a').attr('href', suggestedUser.html_url).text(suggestedUser.login);
        } else {
            $(selector).hide();
        }
    }
    function onError(e) {
        console.log(['ERROR: Line ', e.lineno, ' in ', e.filename, ': ', e.message].join(''));
    }
    worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
        if(subscriberIDs[e.data.cmd]) {
            renderSuggestion(e.data.msg, '.suggestion[data-id="' + e.data.cmd + '"]');
        }
    }, false);

    worker.addEventListener('error', onError, false);

    $(".subscribe").on('click', function () {
        var subID = idGen();
        subscriberIDs[subID] = true;
        $('#subscriptions').append(createSubEl(subID));
        worker.postMessage({cmd: 'subscribe', msg: {subscription: 'github/users', subscriberID: subID} });  
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.unsubscribe', function (e) {
        var subID = $(this).closest('.suggestion').detach().data('id');
        delete subscriberIDs[subID];
        worker.postMessage({cmd: 'unsubscribe', msg: {subscription: 'github/users', subscriberID: subID} });  
    });
    $('#updateTime').on('change', function () {
        var timeVal = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
        worker.postMessage({cmd: 'updateSubTime', msg: {subscription: 'github/users', time: timeVal } });
    })

    function createSubEl(subscriberID) {
        return $('<div class="suggestion" style="visibility:hidden;"><input type="button" value="unsubscribe" class="unsubscribe pull-right btn btn-info"><img /><a href="#" target="_blank" class="username">this will not be displayed</a></div>').data('id', subscriberID); //Note that it's only necessary to set subscriberID on the div container, and by using jQuery the ES6>>>ES5 transpiler has less to do :)
    }
});
```

Comment: John, as you know, your suggested edit was correct. I don't know why it was rejected.